# Laravel - How to execute store resource?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, crud

> I'm creating a CRUD app. But when I code in method store I have a problem: I'm trying to create a variable `$contact = new Contact()`. It's message: `Undefined type 'App\Contact'`.

> This ContactController.php

```
    use App\Contact;
    ....
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required'
        ]);
        $contact = new Contact([
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'job_title' => $request->get('job_title'),
            'city' => $request->get('city'),
            'country' => $request->get('country')
        ]);
        $contact->save();
        return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact saved!');

    }
```

> I made it with this link: https://medium.com/techiediaries-com/laravel-7-crud-tutorial-build-a-crud-app-with-mysql-and-bootstrap-4-4ed8e94f2db0

Comment: ues App\Contact; <= there is a typo (use)

Comment: Is there a `contact.php` file in the `app` folder?

Comment: No . it's app/Models/Contact.php

Comment: `use App\Models\Contact` then run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Please consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here are your option to create:
Option 1:

```
$contact = Contact::create([
    'first_name' => $request->get('first_name')
]);
```

Option 2:

```
$contact = new Contact();
$contact->first_name = 'test';
$contact->save();
```

Also in your contact class, check your namespace. And, use the namespace in the controller as:

> use App\Models\Contact; //since you said your contact.php is inside models folder

Answer (score 0):

you keep controller simple and clean to use this

```
use App\Contact; // if use laravel 7
use App\Models\Contact // if use laravel 8
....
public function store(Request $request, Contact $contact)
{
    $request->validate([
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required'
    ]);

     $contact->create($request->all());
    
    return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact saved!');

}
```

in function update

```
use App\Contact;
    ....
    public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact)
    {
        $id = $contact->id; // if use Route resource 
        $id = $request->id; // if use Route Post


        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=> 'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required'
        ]);

         $date = $request->except(['_token','_method']);

         $contact->where('id', $id)->update($date);
        
        return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact updated!');

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem fixed hihi .